# Use the Fluent API to create a one-to-one relationship between two tables' alternate keys

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm attempting to join two tables in two databases, where the tables have have auto-increment, primary keys and string, alternate keys.  The alternate keys in each system's table have been populated to allow data to be compared (joined).

I have two classes:

Unit (system A)

```
public class Unit
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // alternate key
    public string UnitNumber { get; set; }
    ...
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

Vehicle (system B)

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleSerialNo { get; set; }
    // alternate key
    public string VehicleID { get; set; }
    ...
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create a one-to-one relationship between `Unit.UnitNumber = Vehicle.VehicleID`.

I tried to define this relationship, but have been unsuccessful:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
    .HasAlternateKey("VehicleID");

modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
    .HasAlternateKey("UnitNumber");

modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
    .HasOne<Unit>()
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("VehicleID");

modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
    .HasOne<Vehicle>()
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("UnitNumber");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You must choose one of the entities to be the primary (principal), respectively the other to be secondary (dependent). Principal is the one you create first and can exists w/o the other. The dependent cannot exist w/o principal. Once you make that decision, the relationship can be configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more-difficult than expected:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
    .HasOne(v => v.Unit)
    .WithOne(u => u.Vehicle)
    .HasForeignKey<Unit>(u => u.UnitNumber)
    .HasPrincipalKey<Vehicle>(v => v.VehicleID);
```